# Call C# method from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I try to use jQuery slide for price, as in this picture

[image]

So the user can filter the result as he want,
the jQuery code that i used is as follows:

```
 <script>
    var min = parseInt($('#<%=lbmin.ClientID%>').html());
    var max = parseInt($('#<%=lbMax.ClientID%>').html());
    var Smin = parseInt($('#<%=lbrangeMin.ClientID%>').html());
    var Smax = parseInt($('#<%=lbrangeMax.ClientID%>').html());
    if (Smin = isNaN )
    {
        Smin = min;
    }
    if (Smax = isNaN) {
        Smax = max;
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: min,
            max: max,
            values: [Smin, Smax],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var start = parseInt(ui.values[0]);
                var end = parseInt(ui.values[1]);
                $("#amount").val($('#<%=hfCur.ClientID%>').val() + " " + ui.values[0] + " - " + $('#<%=hfCur.ClientID%>').val() + " " + ui.values[1]);
                $('#<%=lbrange.ClientID%>').html(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                $('#<%=lbrangeMin.ClientID%>').html(ui.values[0] );
                $('#<%=lbrangeMax.ClientID%>').html(ui.values[1]);
                $('#<%=hfrange.ClientID%>').val(ui.values[1]);
          }

      });
        $("#amount").val($('#<%=hfCur.ClientID%>').val() + " " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - " + $('#<%=hfCur.ClientID%>').val() + " " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
```

So when page loads the first time min and max value will set on the label lbmin and lbmax, and when the user pulls the tape the range will change as pulling. and the value will set in other label lbrangeMin and lbrangeMax.
and until now everything works fine,

my request is: I need to run C# method like

```
protected void ttt()
{ some code }
```

I found several solutions, but all of it using a static method with a return value, and another thing when page post-back the ring should not reset.

Comment: C# runs on the server, jQuery/JavaScript on the client (browser). Therefore, they can not call each other directly. You may consider using AJAX.

Comment: Just to slightly extend @chade_'s comment: You can have a C# method that sets/influences javascript code **before** the page is sent to the browser (since the server creates the page content). But you cannot have a C# method that responds to the user's actions when the page has already been sent to the browser. At least, not directly. You need a way for the browser to send a request to/receive a response from the server. Without page reloading, AJAX is indeed the way to go.

Comment: dear @chade_ , yes I understand that because that I search for a solution. thanks dear

Comment: You may want to proof-read your `if`s